# SSRS - Pass muliple hard coded drill down parameters

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssas, drilldown

I am building an SSRS report using SSAS as the data source, and I need a drill down to include 4 of 6 account stages within my account population. The problem stems from not being able to use the [All] member because I only need 4 of the 6 stages.

Is there a way to pass multiple values to the drill down report, by building a list of hard coded parameters I want to use?

I think the Join function my work, but I have been unsuccessful so far.

Comment: we've got lots of cubes at work and also RS; I need to spend a mth doing R&D on this sort of development. I bought [this book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Microsoft-Server-Reporting-Services-Recipes/dp/0470563117/ref=pd_sim_b_2) in preparation and it looks like it's got lots of SSAS to RS information in it. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had a similar situation in which we wanted a drill down report to display two categories of items rather than just one.

We couldn't find an elegant work around, tried placing arrays in the parameter, and almost went as far as to write a function that returned a table.

We slapped ourselves on the face when we realized that you just add another parameter passing the same attribute with the second value.

*Example below:*

`I have 3 types of item. I have 2 cells in a report. One of which I want to drill down to a report on Type 1, and the other I want to drill down to the same report on Type 2 and Type 3.`

For the cell I want to drill to Type 1, we used the Parameters! function, but for the Type 2 and 3 drill down we just hard coded the type parameter in twice.

Once to pass Type 2 and once to pass Type 3.

It is not elegant, but it works.

Comment: I never thought of doing it that way. What I did was add a dataset filter and dynamically set that. Much harder than what you did. Thanks!